# How to display razor partial views based on different HTML forms submit conditions?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

### My page contains multiple partial pages like this. Suppose there are two partial views. And both of those views have their own forms.

```
<div class="row">
@await Html.PartialAsync("_partialNameInfo")       //For First and Last 
Name                
@await Html.PartialAsync("_partialAddressInfo")   // For address info
</div>
```

### partialNameInfo looks similar to this:

```
<form id="nameinfo">
<input type="text" id="firstname"/>
<input type="text" id="lastname"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="checknames()" value="Submit"/>
<form>

//Also, there is JS function checknames similar to this which stores names in json format

<script type="javascript">
function checknames() {      
var namedetails= 
{
   fname : document.getelementbyid .... // gets firstname and stores
   lname : document.getelementbyid .... // gets lastname and stores
};
</script>


//_partialAddressInfo looks similar to this:

<form id="addressinfo">
<input type="text" id="StreetName"/>
<input type="text" id="ApartmentNumber"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<form>
```

What I want it to be like:

1. It should only load first page view by default i.e _partialNameInfo
2. When _partialNameInfo forms validation is correct, then on clicking its Submit button, it should pass the values of checknames and also display 
   another view _partialAddressInfo as first page view is valid.

A. How can I load only the _partialNameInfo page by default ? And not display the other page
B. How to check condition that first page form was correctly submitted so that another page can be displayed?

C. How to pass information obtained from checknames to another view ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `return PartialView()` to render the other page when the first page was correctly submitted.And pay attention to that the `input` type should be `button` not `submit`.

Here is a simple workaround like below:

1.Model:

```
public class NameInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

2._partialNameInfo.cshtml:

```
<form id="nameinfo">
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<input type="button" onclick="checknames()" value="Submit" />
```

3._partialAddressInfo.cshtml:

```
@model Address
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StreetName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApartmentNumber)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StreetName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ApartmentNumber)
                </td>
            </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

4.Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="partial1">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_partialNameInfo")
</div>
<div id="partial2">
</div>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function checknames() {
        var flag;
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var data = { firstname, lastname };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Test",
            type: "POST",
            data :data,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#partial2").html(result);               
            }
        })  
    }
</script>
}
```

5.Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(NameInfo nameInfo)
{
    var model = new List<NameInfo>()
    {
        new NameInfo(){ Id=1,FirstName="a",LastName="b",Address=new Address(){ StreetName="aa",ApartmentNumber=1001} },
        new NameInfo(){ Id=2,FirstName="c",LastName="d",Address=new Address(){ StreetName="bb",ApartmentNumber=1002} }
    };
    var data = model.Where(m => m.FirstName == nameInfo.FirstName).Where(m => m.LastName == nameInfo.LastName).Select(m => m.Address).FirstOrDefault();
    return PartialView("_partialAddressInfo",data);
}
```

6.Result:
[image]